# Where is flutter.compileSdkVersion?

Tags: flutter

While building flutter app, I am getting this error.

```
One or more plugins require a higher Android SDK version.
Fix this issue by adding the following to C:\flutter\projects\my_app\android\app\build.gradle:
android {
  compileSdkVersion 33
  ...
}
```

However, in my build.gradle I have :

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
...
}
```

But I am unable to find the location where flutter.compileSdkVersion is defined. Any idea where is this defined? I have already run flutter upgrade and flutter --version returns Flutter 3.0.5.

Comment: It belongs to flutter core, I think so

Comment: You have just to change this: android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
...
}
to :
android {
  compileSdkVersion 33
  ...
}

Comment: Yes, I could do that but I don't want to have this compileSdkVersion defined in multiple places. As of now, it is picking this value flutter.compileSdkVersion from somewhere and I would rather update that.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

### Newer versions of flutter

In recent versions, the setting comes from the flutter installation directory here:

```
<flutter-installation>/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/src/main/groovy/flutter.groovy
```

at the top of the file there is a class named `FlutterExtension`, which sets a number of static variables, e.g.

```
static int compileSdkVersion = 34
```

### Older versions of flutter

To strictly answer your question, the setting comes from the flutter installation directory here:

```
<flutter-installation>\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle
```

### Some options to change the setting:

If you want to have the settings gathered in one place, then you could set it in the file `local.properties` as:

```
flutter.compileSdkVersion=33
```

And you change in your build.gradle in the following way:

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion localProperties.getProperty('flutter.compileSdkVersion').toInteger()
...
}
```

or (obviously) just set the version direct as:

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 33
...
}
```

Comment: after upgrade to the latest version currently . the file only show```def pathToThisDirectory = buildscript.sourceFile.parentFile
apply from: "$pathToThisDirectory/src/main/groovy/flutter.groovy"``` there is no define for sdk version

Comment: @YogiArifWidodo just open that file to see what's inside `src/main/groovy/flutter.groovy`

Answer (score 10):

Every flutter version has a compiledSdkVersion property along with others. As of Flutter 3.3.8, it is 31.

You can access the code here
https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/flutter/flutter/+/refs/heads/dev/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle#33

In future it might be more than 33. In case you hardcode value as 33, flutter might stop building with errors.

So the solution should be

`compileSdkVersion Math.max(flutter.compileSdkVersion, 33)`

now, in future if flutter changes the property to say 35, your code won't break.

Answer (score 4):

In the latest version, the path has been changed from
`flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle`

to

`/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/src/main/groovy/flutter.groovy`

The defaults are following

```dart
class FlutterExtension {
    /** Sets the compileSdkVersion used by default in Flutter app projects. */
    static int compileSdkVersion = 33

    /** Sets the minSdkVersion used by default in Flutter app projects. */
    static int minSdkVersion = 19

    /**
     * Sets the targetSdkVersion used by default in Flutter app projects.
     * targetSdkVersion should always be the latest available stable version.
     *
     * See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.
     */
    static int targetSdkVersion = 33

    /**
     * Sets the ndkVersion used by default in Flutter app projects.
     * Chosen as default version of the AGP version below as found in
     * https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/install-ndk#default-ndk-per-agp.
     */
    static String ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"

    /**
     * Specifies the relative directory to the Flutter project directory.
     * In an app project, this is ../.. since the app's build.gradle is under android/app.
     */
    String source

    /** Allows to override the target file. Otherwise, the target is lib/main.dart. */
    String target
}
```

Comment: In 2024 this should be the accepted an best answer.

Answer (score 0):

**flutter.compileSdkVersion** is the default version that defaults to installed flutter version configs.
You can replace **flutter.compileSdkVersion** to your own custom version.

Answer (score 0):

yes, and there you need to change it.
replace:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
...
}
```

with this:

```
 android {
  compileSdkVersion 33
  ...
  }
```

`flutter.compileSdkVersion` just the default one got from the flutter sdk.

Answer (score -1):

Open the android folder.
open the App folder.
open the build.gradle from app folder.