# I am facing a problem with tflite and flutter Iwant to solve this problem please

Tags: dart

I hope to solve this problem
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\fox\untitled\android\app\build.gradle' line: 30
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Could not find method compileSdkVersion() for arguments [28] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

[Image of prblem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bVbq.png)

Comment: but what about the problem of "tflite"

Comment: Please post text as text, not images of text

Answer (score 1):

Look here. You just need to make sure you have the appropriate lines in your gradle file.

[Where is flutter.compileSdkVersion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74446016/where-is-flutter-compilesdkversion)